# Raspberry Pi & Waveshare

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to hook up a Raspberry Pi model B to a waveshare e-Paper Hat (2.9 inch). Is this the correct pin connection:

E-paper --> Raspberry Pi

```
3V3 --> Pin 1 
GND --> Pin 9
DIN --> Pin 38 (SPI1 MOSI)
CLK --> Pin 40 (SPI1 SCLK)
CS --> Pin 24 (CE0)
DC --> Pin 25 (GPIO 25)
RST --> Pin 11 (GPIO 17)
BUSY --> Pin 24 (GPIO 24)
```

How correct are they?

I made my selections by matching the keywords in the following two images, but I'm not very confident in my selection:
1) https://www.google.de/search?biw=1680&bih=919&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=f1l0WrrRCsmvkwWR3qWoDg&q=raspberry+pi+3b+pins&oq=raspberry+pi+3b+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l10.13619.14818.0.16673.9.7.0.0.0.0.350.773.4j1j0j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.5.684...0i24k1.0.aa6CSQJJX80#imgrc=uzJLoQO8mMNq7M:
2) https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.13inch_e-Paper_HAT#Working_with_Raspberry_Pi

Comment: You may want to ask this on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/